# Como colocar um card fixo e responsivo em cima do mapa?

Tags: html, css, ionic3

Estou tentando deixar fixo um card em cima do mapa do google maps... Mas não sei como faço para fixar e ficar responsivo também...

Minhas versões

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI          : 5.4.16
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.9
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.4
```

Estou utilizando um CSS para fazer a sobreposição e também posicionar ele no lugar que eu quero:

```
.minhaRegiao {
    width: 90%;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 5%;
    justify-content: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 80%;
    z-index: 9999;
    background-color: #522;
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}
```

E no html uma div simples:

```
<div class="row minhaRegiao">
    <p style="color: white;">Minha Regiao</p>
</div>
```

**Coloquei o [código no fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/pc6w1jdL/) pra ajudar...**

Gostaria que o card sempre ficasse acima do GOOGLE ali no canto inferior esquerdo
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas quando as dimensões mudam, o card também sobe
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta e reduzir o problema a um [mcve] (inclusive, que não dependa de links externos - estes podem servir só como complemento), junto com a tentativa de solução. Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler  [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e o [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70). Ao editar o post conforme orientado, a pergunta vai para uma fila de revisão da comunidade automaticamente.

Comment: Não resolveu ainda, mas já melhorou (mais detalhes nos links), de qualquer forma já posso adiantar que o problema maior é que sua div não faz parte do mapa. Quando quer por algo no mapa do google maps, é bom você criar o material dinamicamente, usando a API do próprio mapa. Não lembro o nome do método, mas se vc der um createElement com a div, pode inserir como elemento nativo depois. Recomendo uma estudada nessa parte da API, vai facilitar muito sua vida. O MapBoxGL também é uma alternativa interessante (além de menos poluído, dependendo do uso) e tem um free tier bem generoso.

Comment: O post está fechado, mas os comments funcionam, então pro caso específico dá pra ajudar por aqui. Aqui tem um exemplo bem legal de uma DIV criada dentro do mapa: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/control-custom - note que é uma div mesmo. No  seu caso, basta não por a parte do clique, se quer apenas um elemento informativo.

Comment: @Bacco eu estava fazendo desta forma, se nao me engano peguei deste mesmo link que me mandou... Mas aconteceu o mesmo, ao mudar a resolução do device, a div subia...

Comment: Pq tipo, em qualquer um dos cenarios, seja fazendo dentro do mapa, ou da forma que eu publiquei aqui, eu preciso colocar um margin para que nao fique colado na parte inferior...

Comment: e para este caso em especifico eu preciso colocar um componente alem do meu texto ali, é um item estatico tambem, mas quando eu tentei renderizar, o componente nao apareceu... entao outro ponto q decidi usar fora....

Comment: Eu acredito que vai acabar complicando um pouco fazer fora. O que vc pode fazer então é isso: <div #meumapa position relative margin 0 padding 0><div #map></div><div #leohenrique position absolute bottom:tanto left:tanto></div> - assim ela vai ficar relativa ao #meumapa, e o #map do google vc poe em 100% de largura e altura. Essa div externa seria pro google nao interferir no seu CSS, mas pra fazer que as 2 coisas se alinhem

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Uma maneira de resolver o problema é adicionar um [`customcontrol`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/control-custom) na instância do  google maps.

Isso vai adicionar um controle personalizado em uma camada acima do mapa, é possível escolher a posição onde ele será visualizado. Em meu exemplo estou usando na posição `top center` mas existem várias possíbilidades para posicionar o elemento de acordo com o que deseja. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls)

> Como colocar um card fixo e responsivo em cima do mapa?

Para isso basta adicionar a classe css style width: 100% ao seu controle.

Segue o código que deixa o controle responsivo:

```
   #mensagem {
       width: 50%;
   }
```

Repare que aqui estamos atribuindo esta classe css ao elemento com id "mensagem".

---

Segue o exemplo completo que mostra como adicionar um controle personalizado:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Custom control gmap</title>
  <style>
    #map-canvas {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }

    #mensagem {
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
      background: #522;
      width: 50%;
    }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  <div id="mensagem">
    <h3>Minha região</h3>
  </div>
  <script>
    
    showMap = () => {
      const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
         center: { lat: -7.2245007, lng: -35.8798429}, zoom: 8
      });

      const custommessage = document.getElementById('mensagem');
      
      map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(custommessage);
    }
  </script>
  <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=showMap">
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

## Explicando o código:

No corpo do html criamos o elemento "map-canvas" que é uma div que receberá a instância do google maps.
No elemento "mensagem" inserimos o texto que queremos usar como um controle customizado, este controle personalizado possui o texto "minha região".

Dentro da tag script na função `showMap` faço a instânciação do google maps e atribuímos ao nosso elemento "map-canvas". O mapa está centralizado na cidade de Campina Grande - PB e possui o zoom com valor 8.

Depois pegamos o elemento "mensagem" e adicionamos como um controle personalizado do nosso mapa, com a posição `top-center`.

Se quer posicionar o elemento na posição inferior esquerda poderia tentar a posição `BOTTOM_LEFT`.

Este exemplo foi inspirado na api atual do [google maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple) e seus exemplos.

Comment: então, eu tentei fazer parecido com o que voce colocou e para mim nao ficou responsivo... quando a resolução do device muda, a div tambem sobe... Vou tentar fazer exatamente como mostrou pra ver se fica diferente

Comment: @LeoHenrique, talvez então o problema esteja em seu css, vou editar a resposta para adicionar o meu css.

Comment: uma coisa q eu nao tinha tentado era fazer a div no HTML e dar um getElementById pra conseguir renderizar junto ao mapa essa div q eu ja tinha criado... E funcionou, obrigado